# What is the number after 19? 1,4,8,13,19

Tags: mathematics

It's a question on the application for my it certification school

Comment: Hah! OEIS, the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C8%2C13%2C19&language=english&go=Search) give **52** series that begin with these 5 terms!

Comment: You might want to check out https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do .  This type of question has been done to death on this site, and unless there is something particularly interesting or unique about it, you're liable to get a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is

> 26

Explanation:

> The gap between the numbers starts at 3 and gets larger each time.
>
>  1 + 3 = 4
>  4 + 4 = 8
>  8 + 5 = 13
>  13 + 6 = 19
>  19 + 7 = 26